# How to configure multiple physical ethernet ports in RHEL6?

Tags: linux, rhel, ip, network-interface, ifconfig

I have an appliance with 4 ethernet ports (eth0, eth1, eth2, and eth3).  I have configured some of the ports such that the results of `ifconfig` is as follows:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0B:68:D9:ED
          inet addr:192.168.0.81  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:1c0:5200:e950:290:bff:fe68:d9ed/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:bff:fe68:d9ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3382 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9717 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:363791 (355.2 KiB)  TX bytes:13339318 (12.7 MiB)
          Memory:dfe60000-dfe7ffff

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0B:68:D9:EE
          inet addr:192.168.0.90  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2919 (2.8 KiB)  TX bytes:438 (438.0 b)
          Memory:dfe40000-dfe5ffff

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:0B:68:D9:F0
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::290:bff:fe68:d9f0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20454 (19.9 KiB)  TX bytes:618 (618.0 b)
          Memory:dfe00000-dfe1ffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11986 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14067159 (13.4 MiB)  TX bytes:14067159 (13.4 MiB)
```

So, my problem is that each IP address (the ones linked to eth0, eth1, and eth3) are ONLY accessible when I have the ethernet cable plugged into eth0.  I can ping all 3 of them when the cable is plugged into eth0.  I cannot ping ANY of them when plugged into eth1 and eth3.  The link lights turn on when I plug them into eth1 and eth3.

When I run `ethtool eth3`, it does say `Link detected: yes`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I addressed this issue in this Q/A:  [Ghost ping on a multi-NIC Linux system](https://serverfault.com/questions/900385/ghost-ping-on-a-multi-nic-linux-system/900958#900958). Note that every detail count, and that it would require a very long answer to explain all the corner cases (but they can all be explained). Using this method (arp_filter + ip rule) allows  keeping rp_filter on, thus still allowing ip spoofing protection AND will actually use all the wires, not just "the first elected".

Comment: You should also consider why you'd want multiple interfaces in the same LAN. For example if that's for redundency, consider using a bond/team interface enslaving all your real interfaces instead. You can still assign multiple IPs on the same interface

Comment: Thanks for these answers, they are helpful.  As you mentioned, the problem seems to go away if I change the ports to use different subnets.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with something called **Asymmetric Routing** — a packet received on one interface will have its response sent on another interface, making some of the IP addresses not reachable from outside the network.

In this case, the ICMP ping requests received on `eth1,2,3` are routed back to `eth0` which, if not physically connected to the network, won't be able to respond on behalf of `eth1,2,3`. The solution is to change the default value of reverse path filter `rp_filter` kernel parameter from 1 to 2, so all the interfaces respond independently of each other.

1. Edit the `/etc/sysctl.conf` to include,

   ```
   $ grep '.rp_filter' /etc/sysctl.conf
   net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
   net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
   net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter = 2
   net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter = 2
   net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter = 2
   net.ipv4.conf.eth3.rp_filter = 2
   ```
2. Reload the configuration:

   ```
   $ sysctl -p
   ```

Read more about the issue [here](http://z-issue.com/wp/linux-rhel-6-centos-6-two-nics-in-the-same-subnet-but-secondary-doesnt-ping/) and [there](http://jensd.be/468/linux/two-network-cards-rp_filter).

Comment: All you said is true, but I don't believe it will solve the problem. Nothing will tell the system to not use eth0 if unplugged. The interface would have to be brought down (ip link set eth0 down) to change the 1st route entry thus electing an other outgoing interface (but then possibly deleting the default route etc..)

Comment: Thanks, I can't check this solution out now, but will respond back when I do.

Comment: @A.B, that's exactly the intention -- making the system to not to treat an interface preferentially over others. The idea is to make interfaces independent of each other even though they're in the same subnet. Unless reverse path validation is set to 2 -- Loose Reverse Path validation (RFC3704), two or more interfaces having IPs in the same subnet won't behave as intended. Do note that this issue wasn't in RHEL 5 which was using kernel-2.6.18 in which `rp_filter` setting was boolean 0 & 1; RHEL 6 uses  ≥kernel-2.6.32 wherein `rp_filter` setting got changed to integer [0,1,2].